# Extracting multiple values from a character field into a new data table

Tags: r, dataframe

My data looks like the following:

```
ids <- c(1,2,3)
titles <- c("Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3")
tags <- c("<self-help><motivation>", "<programming><r><data.frame>", "<photography>")
df <- data.frame(id = ids, title = titles, tags = tags)
df
```

Output:

```
   id  title                         tags
1   1 Entry1      <self-help><motivation>
2   2 Entry2 <programming><r><data.frame>
3   3 Entry3                <photography>
```

I'm struggling to extract out the tags into a new data frame. What I want is a second data frame that looks like this:

```
  id         tag
1  1   self-help
2  1  motivation
3  2 programming
4  2           r
5  2  data.frame
6  3 photography
```

I've managed to do *something* with lists using the following, but the resulting column seems to be nested somehow. My attempts to `unlist()` either have no effect or produce too many entries in the resulting vector.

```
df$tags_list <- lapply(df$tags, function(x)strsplit(gsub("^.|.$", "", x), "><")[[1]])
```

My question is: can someone please help me generate this new `data.frame` (or `data.table`) given `df` as shown here? Any words of wisdom on how to deal with nested lists in general are greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `base R` version `3.2.0+` you could try:

```
lst <- strsplit(gsub("^<|>$", "", df$tags), split="><")
data.frame(id=rep(df$id, lengths(lst)), tags_list=unlist(lst))
#   id   tags_list
# 1  1   self-help
# 2  1  motivation
# 3  2 programming
# 4  2           r
# 5  2  data.frame
# 6  3 photography
```

With `gsub("^<|>$"..)` we eliminate beginning and terminal brackets leaving the pattern `"><"` as word separators. Then we create the data frame with the ids and the separated list.

**Update**

The function `lengths` was added in R 3.2.0 and does for lists what `length` similarly does for vectors. Before it was required to use `sapply(lst, length)`.

Comment: What's the `lengths` function?

Comment: @Spacedman New in R 3.2.0, quite a bit faster than `sapply(x, length)`

Comment: Okay, have the +1 back for using base R. Works with `sapply` as a replacement for us non-yet-upgraders.

Comment: That was included two upgrades ago. Update :)

Comment: What's `?lengths` ? Add some description about this since I can't able to install 3.2 version.

Comment: @AvinashRaj replace `lengths(lst)` with `sapply(lst, length)` and it should work back to version 0.something quite probably...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work unless the `id`s are monotonically incrementing in the source df. Try with `ids <- c(1,4,3)` for example.

Comment: `rep(df$id, lengths(lst))`

Comment: Ah, that's obvious in hindsight. This answer is the highest voted and uses pure R so I'm awarding it as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`tidyr::unnest` to the rescue...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # for %>%

df$tags2 <- strsplit(gsub("^.|.$", "", df$tags), "><")

df %>%
  unnest(tags2)

#   id  title                         tags       tags2
# 1  1 Entry1      <self-help><motivation>   self-help
# 2  1 Entry1      <self-help><motivation>  motivation
# 3  2 Entry2 <programming><r><data.frame> programming
# 4  2 Entry2 <programming><r><data.frame>           r
# 5  2 Entry2 <programming><r><data.frame>  data.frame
# 6  3 Entry3                <photography> photography
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`:

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(transform(df, tags=gsub('^<|>$','', tags)), 'tags', sep='><', direction='long')
#   id  title        tags
#1:  1 Entry1   self-help
#2:  1 Entry1  motivation
#3:  2 Entry2 programming
#4:  2 Entry2           r
#5:  2 Entry2  data.frame
#6:  3 Entry3 photography
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `stri_extract_all` from `library(stringi)` with `melt`

```
library(stringi)
library(reshape2)
melt(setNames(stri_extract_all_regex(df$tags, '[^<>]+'), df$id))
```

Comment: Two comments: `df$id` changed type to `chr` in the output (no big deal), but also this method was staggeringly slow (~2 minutes) compared to the other three methods (sub-second) on 200k rows.

Comment: @dwurf I guess it is the `melt` that slows the process, The `stri_extract` is very fast.